# Hidden column appear after a choice is made

Tags: 2010

Creating a simple document library after the user upload the document. Having an option call sections that is a choice column. When the user make their selection other columns would appear base upon their choice. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Enterprise License for SharePoint? Can you use InfoPath? If not JavaScript and JQuery based solution will work!

Comment: Yes I do have enterprise License, rather SharePoint or Sharepoint designer. I'll look more into Javascript or Jquery based for a solution.

Comment: you can use InfoPath and it will be a lot easier and manageable to customize the Document Library forms with InfoPath! In InfoPath use Rules to show/hide OR Enable/Disable fields based on selection of other fields..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean cascaded dropdown. 
There is a JavaScript-only solution which I used successfully after reading this blog post:

http://jassimkhan.blogspot.de/2010/10/implement-cascading-dropdown-in.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback not looking for a cascading down option but more of after the user make their select other column will appear.